# Selection of actions based on distribution of rewards

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl

In "A Distributional Perspective on Reinforcement Learning" Bellamare et. al. 2017.  We find the following phrase.

> As in DQN, we use a simple $\epsilon$-greedy policy over the expected action values; we leave as future work the many ways in which an agent could select actions on the basis of the full distribution.

Did I miss the strategy used in the paper?  I understand $\epsilon$-greedy but how were distributions compared to determine which action is the greediest?  Q is the reward with the maximum likelihood, etc?

Has there been published research on the "many ways" this can be solved yet?

Answer (score 3):

In distributional value functions, you can still calculate a single *expected* action value, by summing over the distribution. You can use that to select a greedy action for $\epsilon$-greedy policies.

So in practice this is the same as the non-distributional approach, but with a sum to get expected Q predicted by the distributional q function

Comment: It is my understanding that distributional RL seeks to derive some further actionable insight than the estimated mean Q value of traditional RL.  If we only sum over the distribution does that not result in the mean or something with the same action as the mean?

Comment: @foreverska not necessarily, one more direct benefit of a distributional model is that it is more apt and stable. E.g for win/draw/lose results of a game, it's a good choice, and a more informative model even if optimal choice would be the same. Perhaps worth a separate question though

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this fully answers your question, but, as a related fact, the return distribution you get with distributional RL can be used as a mean to "alter" the policy in a smart way.

What I mean is that with the return distribution you also get the *uncertainty* related to the returns, and from this you can introduce the notion of *risk*. Basically, you have a distortion risk measure, $\beta$, which is a function that can transform your return distribution altering the way the policy would sample actions, since the underlying distribution has changed.

Once you apply a specific implementation of risk, you can make your policy to act more conservatively for example, therefore expecting to exhibit a safer behavior, e.g., in more uncertain environments.

[image]

- The picture compares DQN (non-distributional) with IQN (a distributional agent), with different risk measures.
- As you can see the sampling distribution of the actions (so the policy) can be influenced by the specific notion of risk.

This is called *risk-sensitive RL*, and is nicely introduced in chapter 4 of the [IQN paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1806.06923), which is a more powerful way to estimate the return distribution compared to C51. I suggest you to checkout the paper for a more in depth understanding.